# Install Composer and configure with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

After reading on web, I learned that XAMPP has php-cli pre-installed and it is accessed by `/opt/lampp/bin/php` . I installed composer using the following and all went well:

```
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | /opt/lampp/bin/php
```

Composer was installed perfectly. After that, I did this to make it global:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now I made a folder called "fb" and made following composer.json file :

```
{"require":{        "facebook/php-sdk-v4":"4.0.*"   }}
```

Now when I type `$ composer install` in terminal, following message is displayed:

```
rohan@sanap:~/Desktop/fb$ composer install
/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory
```

Please help me to use composer. What should I do in following situation?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install composer like so:

```
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | /opt/lampp/bin/php
```

After installation, you should then symlink it by running command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

Then run the command below to allow the 'composer' command to be run globally (this will be run from within the folder where you've just installed composer in which a composer.phar file has just been created):

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: also "mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" worked for me.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV thanks for the comment that was the final touch that was need for mine to work !.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV Your comment should be added to the solution. Running composer without doing this final step doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

1. Enable the php version from xampp globally

   In Terminal run: `sudo gedit /etc/environment`

   Add this inside quote `":/opt/lampp/bin"`

   click save then close everything.

   or `symlink - "ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php"`
2. Install Curl
   `sudo apt-get install curl`
3. Install composer
   `sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
4. `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

now:: try "`composer`" - it should work!

Comment: this answer is more perfect in my case

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. XAMPP has php-cli already installed so there is **no need to install php-cli via apt-get**.

The reason for the above problem is, as PHP is installed as a bundle along with XAMPP, the OS doesn't know it is there. So for this we should **add the XAMPP php to environment variables**. This done by typing following command in terminal

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

Now, I can use my global setup of Composer effortlessly!